# Suppressing sparks when powering motor controller

Tags: motor-controller, spark

When I connect a 36V Li-Ion battery source to a cheap eBay DC motor controller, there's a significant spark on the wire, regardless of connected components.

Should I:

1) Add capacitors to the input wires? If so, what farad and voltages are appropriate?

2) Create inductance by running a battery wire around an iron core?

3) Ignore it and live with my sparkanoia?

4) Something else?

Comment: Any 36VDC commutator-based motor is going to have some arcing.  I think maybe you need to pursue option #3 ;).

Comment: @Stainless: I think OP is getting sparks when connecting the ESC to the battery - not the motor.

Comment: If you are getting sparks **when** you connect the ESC, then the motor controller is powered on and one terminal is making contact before the second.  Add a switch to the lines.

Comment: What connectors are you using?

Comment: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/xt90-s-anti-spark-connector-2pairs-bag.html

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Add capacitors to the input wires? If so, what farad and voltages
>   are appropriate?

No, if you add a capacitor on the device side it will only *increase* the inrush current. A cap on the battery side would have minimal effect as Li-ion batteries have very low impedance and can source current fast.

> 2) Create inductance by running a battery wire around an iron core?

This will only slow down the inrush current, and will probably create problems for your load if it needs to source power directly from the battery with a small time constant (ie a fast change in a motor might create a voltage drop with large enough inductor). A resistor will only burn power.

A good thing might be to use a switch that is rated for the current, the contacts will be designed to minimize and control any arcing that may occur.

Comment: You beat me by 17 seconds. +1

Comment: What is a 'fast enough' inductor?

Comment: There isn't one, a large enough inductor would be more appropriate, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right in the transition voltage where DC electricity turns from faithful companion to mean drunk.

Its arcing behavior is just starting to turn into "does not know pity, or remorse, or fear" - this is why very old building light switches go SNAP - a spring mechanism creates a very large gap very quickly, to snuff the far more aggressive 110VDC arc.

A modern switch can simply endure the arc for half the AC cycle, and it auto-extinguishes at the zero crossing.

A connector is not a good way to do this; you really need a contact method that snaps shut instantly and definitively, and snaps open.  If it dawdles in near-contact, arcing will quickly damage the contact, and could even weld it together.   Ideally, I would imagine connectors which account for this behavior of 30-40V DC by snapping together and apart very abruptly.

Speaking of those, they seem very underpriced for 80A connectors.  I also notice they are not listed by a competent testing lab. For instance, Underwriter's Laboratories places a "RU" mark on components they have tested and certified.

I have also "cheated" and used listed AC-rated parts *with 10 times the DC rating*.  For 37VDC I would use 370V-rated components.  Of course, at your amperage those will be very heavy; I gather this is hobby aviation, so that's a no-go.